# Javascript if statement failing on visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I'm trying to write an javascript function to disable certain fields on a visualforce page if a checkmark field ("locked") is checked.  The javascript is failing and I've isolated the problem to my if statement.  Can someone tell what I"m doing wrong here?  (If I comment out the if statement the rest of the script works fine, and it is getting the value of PA.locked__c fine as well)

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
                   If("{!PA.Locked__c}" == true) {
                       //alert ({!PA.Locked__c});
                       //$('select').css({"border": "transparent","background": "transparent","box-shadow": "none"}).attr('disabled','disabled');
                       //$('textarea').css({"border": "transparent","background": "transparent","box-shadow": "none"}).attr('disabled','disabled');
                       //$('input[type="text"]').css({"border": "transparent","background": "transparent","box-shadow": "none"}).attr('disabled','disabled');
                  }
                }, 1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe, so `If` is basically a variable name, while `if` is a keyword that denotes a branching instruction. Also, you should not compare a Boolean to a String, and you should use strict equality if you're going to do so. All that said, I typically advise that you skip the comparison, because a Boolean value is already a Boolean value. Thus your code should look like this:

```
if({!PA.Locked__c}) {
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:Updated because I got it wrong the first time.

Yes to what @sfdcfox wrote, but also - as written, if `PA.Locked__c` is true, your JS looks like:

```
If("true" == true) {...}
```

In JavaScript, this will evaluate to **FALSE**.

Comment: Actually, `"false" == true` is false (just tried it to confirm my sanity). However, `if("false")` would be true, which is why I recommended removing the quotes entirely.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. In that case, the reverse case is the problem. If `PA.Locked__c` is false, you get `If("true" == true)` which evaluates to **FALSE**.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good reason to avoid using that as well. I always recommend not comparing to true/false anyways, because a Boolean is already a Boolean.